# SQL statement fails under Perl but works from the command line

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to execute a script to update a database:

```
my $sql_hash_update = 'UPDATE user SET hash = $hash , updated = 1 WHERE id = $row[0]';
my $sth_hash_update = $dbh->prepare($sql_hash_update);
$sth_hash_update->execute();
```

I get the error that this is not proper syntax, but this works within SQL itself.

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '[0]' at line 1 at conexion.pl line 32.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print ` $sql_hash_update` and share the results with us? Also, if you're using a prepared statement, why use variable substitution when constructing the SQL?

Comment: @Mureinik I get the variables themselves. I am going to try by concatenating the variables instead of adding them like if it was PHP.

Comment: @PathikVejani: Please remove your comment; it is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using single quotes, so this statement

```
my $sql_hash_update = 'UPDATE user SET hash = $hash , updated = 1 WHERE id = $row[0]'
```

will not interpolate the values of `$hash` and `$row[0]` into the SQL statement. Instead they will be left as they are, and so the statement isn't valid SQL

You could simply switch to double quotes, which do interpolate, but it is best to use *placeholders* like this

```
my $sql_hash_update = 'UPDATE user SET hash = ?, updated = ? WHERE id = ?';

my $sth_hash_update = $dbh->prepare($sql_hash_update);

$sth_hash_update->execute( $hash, 1, $row[0] );
```

That way you avoid the risk of code injection, and you need to `prepare` only once for many different `execute` calls

Placeholders are valid wherever an *expression* is allowed in the SQL syntax. That means, for instance, you cannot provide a placeholder for a table name, because you couldn't put an expression there in an ordinary SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

Perl does not interpolate single quotes so `$row[0]` is not being expanded.
You want double quotes.

However, you should also pass $row[0] as a bind parameter.

Something like:

```
my $sql_hash_update = 'UPDATE user SET hash = ? , updated = 1 WHERE id = ?';
my $sth_hash_update = $dbh->prepare($sql_hash_update);
$sth_hash_update->execute($hash, $row[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quote

```
my $sql_hash_update = "UPDATE user SET hash = $hash , updated = 1 WHERE id = $row[0]";
```

Comment: @Borodin I think you think about the fourth answer that was deleted. That one was completly wrong. This answer is technically ok, tho it should better use placeholders within the statement.

Comment: @Borodin It has worked for me, single quote consider it as a string